How to activate environment variables used in application.properties in testing (Springboot)?
I wanted to do testing in my Springboot (3.2.4) application, but I have a problem. When I launch test it fails with exception because environment variables used in application.properties are not loaded in tests.
For example I have this in my application.properties:
spring.datasource.username=${DB_USER}
spring.datasource.password=${DB_PSW}
And test fails because ${DB_USER} and ${DB_PSW} are not replaced by environment variables.
Is there some easy fix which will load all environment variables while using tests?
Thank you for help.

To load environment variables for your tests in a Spring Boot application, you can use the @TestPropertySource annotation along with @SpringBootTest. This annotation allows you to specify properties files or inline properties to be used during testing.

How are you setting the environment variables when running tests?

@DamodarHegde I tried @TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties") on public class ...Test and it did not help

@Bernie I defined them in IntelliJ in 'Edit configurations' and then 'Environment variables'

@Bernie I found out what was wrong, I defined environment variables only for main class of application. But right now I have to define environment variables for each test class, is there a better solution? I mean to define all environment variables for all test classes at once.

@naruto25 I'd set them in src/test/resources/application.properties as the provided answer suggests. There may be other options that are not so easy, but that's the usual approach. Is there a reason for not doing that? It does mean that all developers (and CI environments) need the same database credentials. If that can't be done, individual developers can override the settings in the test application properties file (but not commit them to version control).

I think that Damodar meant to set the variables explicitly in @TestPropertySource, using the properties field: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/testing/annotations/integration-spring/annotation-testpropertysource.html. This is useful if you want to set properties only for specific tests. To set them for all tests, I'd use src/test/resources/application.properties.

Bernie is right. @TestPropertySource will set variables for a particular test. To set properties for all of your test cases, I'd use src/test/resources/application.properties too. If your values are not being found, I would suggest that you ensure that the file is on the correct classpath.

I have environment variables because I don't want to commit data that would'be been inside application.properties. I set them up in IntelliJ for application running. Later I found out that I can set them for all tests at once for cost (I have tu rerun every test). You are right that I can rewrite application.properties for tests and use only locally and do not commit it. I was just curious if there is a way to have file with environment variables and somehow runned program inside IDE will use it globally even for tests.

And if I want to use environment variables while running command 'maven test' I found out that I have to define them all either in command line or in pom.xml.

If you added your properties to src/main/resources/application.properties, you have to also override your properties in src/test/resources/application.properties, so just add the same file with properties to test package
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-tests-override-properties

I tried to copy application.properties to src/test/resources/ and it did not help
